# How to query three tables in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am building an event website with laravel, my problem is that I want to query the event table in the DB and also organizers table and ticket table, the event table will provide the id which I will use to query the rest of the tables (tickets and organizers) which is linked with the events_id that is in both tickets and organizers

below is the code

```
    $events = Events::orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->leftJoin('organizers', 'events.id', '=', 'organizers.events_id')
    ->leftJoin('tickets', 'events.id', '=', 'tickets.events_id')
    ->paginate(env('EventPag'));
```

here is the code for the events model

```
public function organizers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Organizers');
}
public function tickets(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tickets');
}
```

here is the code for the organizers model

```
public function events(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Events');
}
```

it gave me this error

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'obj.events.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select events.* from `events` left join `organizers` on `events`.`id` = `organizers`.`events_id` left join `tickets` on `events`.`id` = `tickets`.`events_id` group by `events`.`id` order by `events`.`id` desc limit 6)

how can I rectify this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using eloquent correctly

Just fix your get in controller

```php
$events = Events::orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->with(['organizers','events'])
    ->paginate(env('EventPag'));
```

For more info follow this link: [Laravel - Eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: What I want is that for every event, it will load every ticket and organizers, but with this your solution, it will load only one ticket and organizer